# Issues when updating Android Studio from version 3.1.3 to version 3.1.4

Tags: android, updates, android-studio-3.1.4

I upgraded from Android Studio 3.1.3 to Android Studio 3.1.4. The update has completed successfully but now every time I start Android Studio, the following message appears : "Clear Read-Only Status" (See image below).

When I press "ok", I have this message: Failed to change read-only status for the following files (The files listed below):

[image: Screenshot: Failed to change read-only status for the following files (The files listed below)].

I can only press "Cancel" to continue.

When closing Android Studio, a similar message also appears and I have to force the closure (See the image below).

[image: Could not save project: Unable to save project files. Please ensure project files are writable and you have permissions to modify them.]

Has anyone encountered the same issue? How did you solve it?

### Update

I didn't solve the problem but I got over it by deleting the local project's folder. I then cloned it from Git. Fortunately, I didn't have any big unsaved changes. Thanks for continuing to add your suggestions that might help other people.

Comment: Just updated my AS to 3.1.4.. Did not face any problem.. Have you tried going to File->close project. then opening the project by  `open an existing project` from the project window?

Comment: Can you try File -> invalidate cache restart?

Comment: Go to File and select the option Cache Restart, after this restart Android Studio.

Comment: most likely you ran some command as root there before; `sudo chmod -R pzambou:pzambou /home/pzambou/workSpaces/workSpaceAndroid` might have been the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try **File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart** as Android Studio makes a lot of files as caches and does not delete them this could cause problem once updated.